# .htaccess redirect permanent www.domain.com/A to www.domain.com/A/B

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, apostrophe-cms

A is an empty folder, simply used for building up my hierarchy of pages.
It contains B,C which are also folders (non empty)

The hierarchy comes from the **Apostrophe CMS**.

The following rule does not work in .htaccess:

```
Redirect permanent /A http://www.domain.com/A/B
```

because it ends up to : http://www.domain.com/A/B/B/B/B etc since the rule is invoked over and over.

Can anyone point me to a solution ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using RedirectMatch and include the "end of string" $ in the regex.

```
RedirectMatch permanent /A$ http://www.domain.com/A/B
RedirectMatch permanent /A/$ http://www.domain.com/A/B
```

EDIT: The below matches may work somewhat better (at all)

```
RedirectMatch permanent .*/A$ http://www.domain.com/A/B
RedirectMatch permanent .*/A/$ http://www.domain.com/A/B
```